# Pose Estimation: Where is my error in reasoning?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to do pose estimation. But I am clearly doing something wrong.
I calibrated my camera using  a [charuco board](http://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d13/tutorial_aruco_calibration.html#gsc.tab=0). Pose estimation with it works, so I guess there is no error in my calibration data.

Ok, let's say I have a pattern consisting of 4 Markers (A,B,C,D).
Each of these markers has an image coordinate and a pattern coordinate.
The origin of the pattern is the center of the polygon.

[image: Pattern Upright]

The image coordinates (x/y) are the following. (In a 1280x960 image)

> - Origin(616/814)
> - A(561/664)
> - B(702/838)
> - C(637/982)
> - D(520/755)
>
> Pattern coordinates (x/y/z)
>
> - Origin(0/0/0)
> - A(-12/32/0)
> - B(18/-5/0)
> - C(12/-36/0)
> - D(21/13/0)

Now it rotates by 90 degrees, but my coordinate system does not rotate with the pattern.
 I am wondering what is wrong? Is it because the Z coordinate is always 0?

[image: Pattern horizontal]

> - (x/y)
> - Origin(632/784)
> - A(718/812)
> - B(567/938)
> - C(441/909)
> - D(632/784)
>
> Pattern coordinates (x/y/z)
>
> - Origin(0/0/0)
> - A(32/12/0)
> - B(-4/18/0)
> - C(-35/11/0)
> - D(11/19/0)

I am using solvePnP like this

```
 cv::solvePnP(patternPoints, imgPoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec);
```

Drawing the axis

```
//Method Call
pattern.drawAxis(image, camMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec,10);

//Implementation (taken from aruco.cpp)

void drawAxis(InputOutputArray _image, InputArray _cameraMatrix, InputArray _distCoeffs,
              InputArray _rvec, InputArray _tvec, float length) {

    CV_Assert(_image.getMat().total() != 0 &&
              (_image.getMat().channels() == 1 || _image.getMat().channels() == 3));
    CV_Assert(length > 0);

    // project axis points
    vector< Point3f > axisPoints;
    axisPoints.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, 0));
    axisPoints.push_back(Point3f(length, 0, 0));
    axisPoints.push_back(Point3f(0, length, 0));
    axisPoints.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, length));
    vector< Point2f > imagePoints;
    projectPoints(axisPoints, _rvec, _tvec, _cameraMatrix, _distCoeffs, imagePoints);

    // draw axis lines
    line(_image, imagePoints[0], imagePoints[1], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
    line(_image, imagePoints[0], imagePoints[2], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
    line(_image, imagePoints[0], imagePoints[3], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
}
```

**Edit: Code to calculate pattern coordinates**

```
void calculateCoordinatesRealtiveToCenter(cv::Point2d center, Marker& p1, double realWorldPixelSize)
{
    double dx = p1.imageCoordinate.x - center.x;
    double dy = center.y - p1.imageCoordinate.y;

    p1.patternCoordinate.x = dx * realWorldPixelSize;
    p1.patternCoordinate.y = dy * realWorldPixelSize;
}
```

Comment: if you expect your camera to move, you may not change the object-coordinates. If I interpret your coordinates right, atm you adjust your object coordinates which means that your camera is fixed and your object moves.

Comment: so please try pattern coodinates:    `Origin(0/0/0)    A(-12/32/0)    B(18/-5/0)     C(12/-36/0)    D(21/13/0)` for your second image, too

Comment: @Micka Thank you, I will try it and come back after.

Comment: @Micka  You were right. With fixed coordinates it works as I wish it. So if you want, you can write an answer and I will accept it,
but I think I am not really understanding how solvePnp works. In your comment you said, that I would expect my camera to move. But actually it's the opposite. I expect my object to move and my camera should be static (In the two images I moved the object). By this I mean that I grab the object with my hands and than rotate it in front of a camera on a tripod.

Comment: how did you choose the "pattern coordinates" if that's in fact what you want to compute? solvePnP computes the "object coordinates" with the assumption that the camera is static at point (0,0,0) which is the same as computing the camera movement with a fixed object location (maybe matrix inverted and depending on multiplication order, see openGL rendering pipeline explanations).

Comment: @Micka I calculate the "pattern coordinates" by calculating a direction vector from a given origin point. (See my edited question for the code).
I have the feeling that I want exactly what you describe, but I just use a wrong conception to describe it. in the end I want to determine where my object is in the real world. What I guess, I can do in the way how you described it. (using fixed "pattern coordinates")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used solvePnP myself, so this might not be 100% true. Previously I've seen people using solvePnP to compute the camera movement instead of object movement, but the documentation says it computes the object position in fact. Here's my interpretation:

`objectPoints – Array of object points in the object coordinate space`
these are the object points in 3D space, but not he global object coordinates, but the object coordinates relative to its own coordinate system. So if the object is solid, these coordinates will be fixed for this object. For example if the coordinate origin of a cube is set to its center of gravity, the corner points will be at positions `(-n,-n,-n);(-n,-n,n);(-n,n,-n)` and so on. No matter how the object is rotated or translated, these object points will be the same, because they are relative to the object's own coordinate system. What you want to compute is the placement of this object coordinate system.

In the end you are interested in either the camera extrinsic parameters (if the scene is fixed) or the object extrinsic parameters (if camera is fixed), but both can be computed the same way (maybe matrix operation order has to be reverted or matrices have to be inverted).

So for your task, you would have this setup:

> ```
> The image coordinates (x/y) are the following. (In a 1280x960 image)
>
>     Origin(616/814)
>
>     A(561/664)
>     B(702/838)
>     C(637/982)
>     D(520/755)
>
> Pattern coordinates (x/y/z)
>
>     Origin(0/0/0)
>     A(-12/32/0)
>     B(18/-5/0)
>     C(12/-36/0)
>     D(21/13/0)
> ```

and for the second image:

> ```
>     (x/y)
>     Origin(632/784)
>
>     A(718/812)
>     B(567/938)
>     C(441/909)
>     D(632/784)
>
> Pattern coordinates (x/y/z)
>
>     Origin(0/0/0)
>     A(-12/32/0)
>     B(18/-5/0)
>     C(12/-36/0)
>     D(21/13/0)
> ```

I'm not sure how you've computed the "pattern coordinates" in YOUR second image. Probably you rotated them with rotating the object, but anyways, you changed the object's intrinsic coordinate system, that's why you observe false results.

Comment: Oh ok, very good explanation! I understand now. Thank you very much!